# NSMutableArray initializing from viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

```
arrayOfElements = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[someObj getArray]];
```

and

```
arrayOfElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arrayOfElements = [someObj getArray];
```

What's the difference?

The first `arrayOfElements` does not seem to lose its objects when it returns count in `numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`, but the second one does. I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I do it the second way.

**EDIT:**

Can I suppose now that this is the best way,

```
arrayOfElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[someObj getArray]];
```

because I am initializing an array with the contents of whatever will be `autorelease`'d, and I now have a fully independent array in the current class, that is `viewDidLoad`, oops sorry, `ViewController`.

Comment: 2nd version is costly. you created an array and dumped it and stored new array to it.

Comment: at second case arrayOfElements will be immutable

Comment: @MarceloFabri Nope. Can you explain why that could matter here?

Comment: @BlackFlam3 If you're not using ARC, then both forms are erroneous.

Comment: @H2CO3 You mean I should release them in viewDidLoad? Like autorelease?

Comment: Is `arrayOfElements` a property or just a straight ivar and how is it declared?

Comment: `NSMutableArray *arrayOfElements;` ? Uhm, is there any other way it could be declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line creates an `NSMutableArray` from an existing array

```
arrayOfElements = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[someObj getArray]];
```

This combination first creates an `NSMutableArray` and then instantly discards it replacing it with what is returned by `[someObj getArray]`

```
arrayOfElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Create new NSMutableArray
arrayOfElements = [someObj getArray];            // Throw away the newly created array and replace with the result of [someObj getArray]
```

If you are not using ARC then it is purely by luck that either would work.

In both cases `arrayOfElements` is being assigned an `autorelease`'d object - which will be cleared soon (most likely the next runloop). It is only by chance that nothing else has been written over this point of memory which allows one of your implementations to still work.

---

If you are not using ARC then really you should update your project to be using it will handle a lot of cases like this for you.

You should definitely be using properties (not bare ivars) as this will help reduce memory issues (for non-ARC) and give a more consistent interface to your code.

In your header (or class extension) declare the property like this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOfElements;
```

Now for ARC you can simple do

```
[self setArrayOfElements:[[someObj getArray] mutableCopy];
```

for non-ARC you can do

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[someObj getArray] mutableCopy];
[self setArrayOfElements:array];
[array release]; array = nil;
```

---

Also note that `getArray` is a bad method name.

> The use of “get” is unnecessary, unless one or more values are returned indirectly.
>   [Coding Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html)

Comment: What's the best solution and why?

Comment: Thanks for the input and the coding guideline also. Helped me learn.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding objects to mutable array from another array, try this:

```
[arrayOfElements addObjectsFromArray: [someObj getArray]];
```

Comment: This would work along with an `NSMutableArray` initialization.

Comment: But actually I am asking for clarification. I want to know why really.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using ARC, you need to make sure its retained.

```
if (arrayOfElements) {
    [arrayOfElements release];
}
arrayOfElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[someObj getArray]];
```